# Automatic data display from database using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a small animation of a path plotted against X and Y values. I need to display the values of X and Y along with the path. The duration of the entire path is fixed and used `attrTween` for smooth animation.

Now I need to display the X and Y values dynamically corresponding to the path.

How do I do this?

My part of code for this is:

```
   text = svg.append("text")
             .data(data.slice(0,1))
             .style("fill","red");

   transition1();

   function transition1() {
       text.transition()
           .duration(data.length*100)
           .attrTween("x",translateAlong1(path.node()))
           .each("end", runNewData);
   }

   function translateAlong1(path) {
       return function(d,i,a) {
           return function(t) {
               var p1 = path.getPointAtLength(t * data.length * 100);
               return "X is " + p1.x + "Y is " + p1.y+;
           };
       };
   }
```

runNewData is another source of data. You can just ignore that.

You can see the java script part here: http://pastebin.com/ARpxEXsq

In the code, leave the database part. Just try on runNewData.

The content of the file is:

x,y,z

0,6,hello

1,5,hi

2,4,a

3,3,c

4,3,b

4,2,a

5,2,b

5,3,a

5,4,c

Comment: Will be easy to help if you can share a link with running code (like jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous, but I am going to assume that you want to show the current x and y position of a circle moving along a path.

One way to do this is as follows:

Append the text element in which you want to show the updated position, before you define the `translateAlong` function, like:

```
text = svg.append("text")
    .style("fill","red");
```

And then inside the `translateAlong` function, update the text as the position of the circle changes:

```
function translateAlong(path) {
    return function(d, i, a) {
        return function(t) {
            var p = path.getPointAtLength(t*data.length*100);
            // Update the text inside the text element:
            text.text("X is " + p.x + "Y is " + p.y);
            return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
         };
    };
}
```